# Fonts appear in different color in buffer

Tags: font-lock

When I write a big text exceeding the window bounds when starting Emacs the fonts appear in other color than the rest. If it makes any good to mention, when I disable font-lock mode text appears in one color as it is.

[image]

Comment: This looks as if whitespace-mode is enabled...

Comment: Do you see the problem when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a step-by-recipe to reproduce the problem. If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `M-x customize-group RET whitespace RET` to customize how `whitespace-mode` works. In particular, you can scroll down to the "Whitespace Style" setting, and uncheck the "Lines, only overlong part" option to turn off this particular effect. Use `C-x C-s` to save the settings, and then reload or revert the buffer to update it.